# JQuery Mobile 1.4 How to Disable Hover Effect on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm having a similar problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers), but with JQuery Mobile 1.4, particularly with the list views. A slight tap that is not enough to be considered a click causes list elements to highlight and stay highlighted:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can prevent any hover highlighting in my application? I would rather not have to modify any of the JQM theming CSS to do this, but I will if that is what it takes.

Comment: can you use a web inspector to see which property is being triggered by the 'hover'? Maybe a background-color change or css filter?

Comment: I don't see anything change when I hover over it. I just see (for example) `<a class="home_item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" id="home_settings" href="#settings" data-ajax="false">Support</a>` The button hover is set with .ui-btn:hover for each swatch in the Themeroller-generated CSS file. I can disable it globally by making the hover colors the same as the normal color, but I was looking for a per-widget solution.

Comment: This may seem a lame answer, but can you move all hover effects into a @media query, say `@media (min-width:1024px)`? I know it's not a catch-all, and you said you'd like to not have to modify CSS, but that would be the quickest way I know of.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like maybe there is a jquery hover event or mouseover being triggered to set the interaction state to something like ".ui-state-hover" or ".state-hover"

**1.**

[jQueryUI - removing class on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795087/jqueryui-removing-class-on-hover)

**2.**

```
function overPrevent(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

$(".options li").hover(overPrevent,outOption);

// alternative to above but still using JavaScript
$(".options li").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus ui-state-hover");
}

 // alternative to above but still using JavaScript
 $(".options li").hover(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
});
```

OR maybe unbind to the mouseenter and mouseleave?

**3.**

```
$('.options  li').click(function(){
     $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
})
```

OR try a pure css override

**4.**

```
.theme-group-header .state-default .corner-all .state-hover:hover{
   background:none;
}
```

also detecting mobile up front with something like this small library - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

then you can name space your css and override the jquery ui library with something roughly like this:

```
.touch{
   .theme-group-header .state-default .corner-all .state-hover:hover{
       background:none;
   }
}
```

**see also references:**

- http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/05/non-hover/
- [jQueryUI - removing class on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795087/jqueryui-removing-class-on-hover)
- http://tech.vg.no/2013/04/10/hover-state-on-touch-devices/
- [The issue with the "ui-state-hover" effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395353/the-issue-with-the-ui-state-hover-effect)
- [Jquery hover function and click through on tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445086/jquery-hover-function-and-click-through-on-tablet)
- [jQuery UI button not "unclicking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800641/jquery-ui-button-not-unclicking)
- http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/
- [mobile safari links retains focus after touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642953/mobile-safari-links-retains-focus-after-touch)
- http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
- https://github.com/kof/remove-hover

Answer (score 2):

To prevent any hover highlighting in a jQuery Mobile 1.4 Listview you can overwrite the appropriate CSS according to the swatch you're using:

```
/* Button hover */
#yourList.ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-color}*/;
}
/* Button down */
#yourList.ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:active {
    background-color: #e8e8e8 /*{a-bdown-background-color}*/;
}
```